# Simple form in Rails Without Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I just started trying to get acquainted with Rails, and I don't really know much Ruby. Currently I'm doing a beginners project to get acquainted with the framework which involves a simple form which takes a name, email, and phone number, and when you hit a submit button the page should refresh and present the information you submitted (so there is no database interaction and the model is supposed to do very little). It's very simple, but as my current knowledge of Ruby is pretty minimal, I'm getting somewhat confused. I've written the views for the most part but I'm still confused on what to put in the controller and the model. If anyone could provide any hints that would be great!

Comment: Have you considered following a tutorial rather than doing it hit-or-miss using SO as the tutorial? http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book It's free, it's good, it'll teach you better than random questions on SO.

Comment: @Dave Newton: thank you for the advice. This was a short assignment given to me by someone else to get acquainted with Ruby so I started the tutorial but didn't complete it. However, I will complete it when I have the chance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Models (at least those descending from ActiveRecord::Base) require a database, so if you are using a model you are using a database, even if its a simple one like SQLite.

If you don't want to descend into models and generating a migration to create the tables for your models, then you are probably just going to store the form values into instance variables and reference those in your view. Below is a quick example how to do that.

If you have a form that sends data (ex: `name` and `email`) to a `create` action, the create action would look sort of like this:

```
def create
  @name = params[:name]
  @email = params[:email]
  render :my_template
end
```

The `create` action above is assigning the params sent to it to instance variables, which you can then reference in your view. In the above example the `create` action is going to try and render a view called `my_template` which would probably be named `my_template.html.erb` and might look something like this:

```
<p>Your name is <%= @name => and your email is <%= @email =>.</p>
```

This is an extremely small and contrived example, but hopefully this helps.

When you move on to working with models your create action might instead create a new instance of a model, pass that model the params sent by the user, save the model, and then redirect them to a page that shows the data.

Answer (score 3):

You need tableless model. Please refer excellent webcast from Ryan on this topic.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/193-tableless-model

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier with a database.

```
rails new stack
cd stack
rm public/index.html
rails generate scaffold Member name:string email:string phone:string
rake db:migrate
rails server
```

Then browse to localhost:3000/members

(Assuming you are using rails 3)

Comment: It's not easier with a DB, it's just more typical.

Comment: You mean to say that two lines of code, the scaffold line and the rake db:migrate line are more complex than what he is doing? Not in rails. Rails is best when you let it be rails, rather than try to use MVC withot a model.

Comment: Yes, because the "magic" confers a learning curve. The scaffolding controller has more methods, the templates are larger, etc. For the specifics of what the OP is asking, and to understand what is working, the accepted answer is substantially easier. Just typing in what you write w/o understanding is *faster*, but not *easier*, based on the OP's needs, and doesn't meet those needs.